# 16進Hexコードを変換して日本語表記したい。

Tags: python, python3

16進Hexコード「5e 3d c3 bd c4 5e c3 bd c4 1b 24 42 23 36 1b 28 4a 20」を日本語で「^=ﾃｽﾄ^ﾃｽﾄ６」と表現できるのですが、encode、decodeを駆使しutf-8,unucode,ISOなど使用し変換を試みているのですが半角文字「ﾃｽﾄ^ﾃｽﾄ」のみ出たり全角の「６」だけでたりでなかなか「^=ﾃｽﾄ^ﾃｽﾄ６」と出てくれません。
どの様にすれば表現できますでしょうか。
ご教授頂ければ幸いです

Comment: 半角カナ文字を0xA1〜0xDFで表現しているのに、ISO-2022-JP互換のエスケープシーケンスを使用しているので、「拡張ISO-2022-JP」と言える変則的な文字エンコーディングのデータですね。私の検索能力では、pythonでそのようなエンコーディングをdecode出来るのかどうかはわかりませんでした。入力の「16進Hexコード」は、Pythonのどのようなデータ型で表現されているのでしょうか? うまくいかなかったコードで構いませんので、ご質問内容を編集してご自身のコードを追記されると、回答を得やすくなると思います。根本的には元の16進表現を作った方に、「メジャーで流通性のある文字エンコーディングを使用してください」とお願いした方が良いような気もします。

Comment: ちなみに`ISO-2022-JP`や`Shift-JIS`が主流になった(今はもっと先のUTF-xxですが)現在ではマイナーに転落していますが、質問に提示されているデータは`-JP`という限定の付かない`ISO-2022`本来の仕様に則っているはずですよ。[文字コードの話](http://euc.jp/i18n/charcode.ja.html) の「第4章 ISO 2022」とか [ISO/IEC 2022 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_2022) など。@metropolis さん回答の compound text encoding の仕様も、よく見れば ISO-2022 に則っているはずです。あるいは最近の話というなら、Javaの[x-windows-iso2022jp](https://wiki.suikawiki.org/n/x-windows-iso2022jp)かもしれませんね。[ISO-2022-JP - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-2022-JP)の「ISO-2022-JPと非標準的拡張使用」の1段落目の最後に記載。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iso-2022-jp-ext`というのが使えるようです。

[半角カナありiso-2022-jpエンコーディング](http://tanakahisateru.hatenablog.jp/entry/20080720/1216565211)

> 万全を期すなら、使用できない文字をフィルタするべきですが、「とりあえず動く」Pythonicな現実解プログラムを書くための現実解としては、
>
> ```
> u'ﾊﾝｶｸ'.encode('iso-2022-jp-ext')
> ```
>
> とします。これで、他の日本語エンコーディングで入力された任意の文字列を、とりあえずiso-2022-jpとして扱うことができます。

上記を応用して、いったん`0x80`以上を`cp932`で`decode`し、`iso-2022-jp-ext`で`encode`し直すことでデータを変換し、再度`iso-2022-jp-ext`で`decode`すれば出来るでしょう。
変更：半角カナが連続しても全て1文字毎に切り替えて冗長だったのを整理

```
data = b'\x5e\x3d\xc3\xbd\xc4\x5e\xc3\xbd\xc4\x1b\x24\x42\x23\x36\x1b\x28\x4a\x20'

work = []
kana = []
for b in data:
  if b < 0x80:
    if kana:
      work.extend(bytes(kana).decode('cp932').encode('iso-2022-jp-ext'))
      kana = []
    work.append(b)
  else:
    kana.append(b)

if kana:
  work.extend(bytes(kana).decode('cp932').encode('iso-2022-jp-ext'))

newdata = bytes(work)

newdata.decode('iso-2022-jp-ext')
```

Answer (score 2):

参考までに、こちらは X Window System の [Compound Text Encoding](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/specs/CTEXT/ctext.html) ではないかと推察します。

[CompoundText(通信用語の基礎知識)](https://www.wdic.org/w/WDIC/CompoundText)

> 特徴
>
> EUCと異なり、何ヶ国語でも混在が可能である。
>
> そこでX Window Systemでは、クライアント(X Window Systemの元で動くプログラム)同士のデータ受け渡しを一旦Compound Textに変換して行なっている。こうすれば個々のクライアントが内部でどのような文字コードを使っていても、矛盾なくデータの受け渡しが可能になる。

参考までに、この「文字列」を Emacs(X Window System version) で表示してみます。

```
$ printf $'\x5e\x3d\xc3\xbd\xc4\x5e\xc3\xbd\xc4\x1b\x24\x42\x23\x36\x1b\x28\x4a\x20\n' > a.txt
```

Emacs で a.txt を読み込んで表示

[image: compound text]

Python で compound text を扱う事が可能なパッケージがあれば、エンコーディングの変換は可能かもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

5e : Shift-JISの `^`
3d : Shift-JISの `=`
c3 : Shift-JISの `ﾃ`
bd : Shift-JISの `ｽ`
c4 : Shift-JISの `ﾄ`
5e : Shift-JISの `^`
c3 : Shift-JISの `ﾃ`
bd : Shift-JISの `ｽ`
c4 : Shift-JISの `ﾄ`
1b 24 42 : ISO-2022-JPのJIS X 0208:1990への切り替え指示
23 36 : JIS X 0208:1990の `６`
1b 28 4a : ISO-2022-JPのJIS C 6220-1976への切り替え指示
20 : JIS C 6220-1976の  （空白）

と複数の文字コードが混在しています。文字コードを理解した上で変換を行う必要があります。